# Show/Hide the Image based on Scrolling in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to show/hide the image based on scrolling. But the condition here is, if the user scrolls up and down many times near the page top/bottom, the image should not fade in and fade out repetitively. It should listen for 1 sec before fade in. Below is the logic that i tried.

**Code**

```
<div class="a" style="height: 300px;width: 300px;background-color: green;position:fixed;">
</div>

var $toTop = $('div.a');
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $toTop.fadeIn();
} else if ($toTop.is(':visible')) {
    $toTop.fadeOut();
}
});
```

Comment: Did you try `$toTop.delay(1000).stop().fadeIn();`...?

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ovadt2ky/?

Comment: can be achieved by using a timer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by saving a timeout in jquery main data object that waits for a second to execute whenever scroll event is fired. The event also clears any previously registered timeouts:

```js
var $toTop = $('div.a');
$(window).scroll(function() {

    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'waitASecond'));
    $toTop.stop();

    $.data(this, 'waitASecond', setTimeout(function() {

     
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
          $toTop.fadeIn();
        } else if ($toTop.is(':visible')) {
          $toTop.fadeOut();
        }

    }, 1000));

});
```

```css
body
{
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  Scroll Down and wait....
      <div class="a" style="height: 700px;width: 300px;background-color: green;display:none"></div>
  
 </body>
```